# Use content script to define global variables

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

I am creating a Firefox extension, and one feature of it that I would like is the ability for the user to inject a script or stylesheet into a specific website, rather like Greasemonkey (except that this will only be for one site). I am adding some functions for the scripts to make use of, which I intended to add from the Content Script into the main (unsafe) window. On the [MDN blog](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/), it says that they have made changes to how it should be implemented, so I have based my code on the new implementation as advised in the post, so this is what I have:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();//Yes, I am also injecting jQuery at the same time
console.log("created jquery object"); //This works
exportFunction($jq, unsafeWindow, {defineAs: "$jq"});
console.log("This will never be called");
```

But execution of the script just stops, and in the console it prints `Message: TypeError: window is null`.
I am testing in Firefox 28 predominantly (I can't seem to get Firefox for Ubuntu to update beyond that right now, and a whole load of issues are forcing me to use Ubuntu in a VM for this), but in Nightly 31a1 (Win7) nothing is ever injected, including a hardcoded style (that works on FF28) so I will have to figure that out at some point. (The PageMod code is here:

```
var lttWorker = sdk.pageMod.PageMod({
    include:["*"],
    /*contentScriptFile: [sdk.data.url("jquery.large.js"), sdk.data.url("scripts/bootstrapper.js")],
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",*/ //This is commented to test whether it was an issue with the script. It's not.
    contentStyle: "#header_bar{background-color:green;}", //This is injected in FF28 but not 31
    attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
    onAttach: function(){desktopNotifications({title:"attached content worker", text:"The content worker has been successfully attached"})} //This is called in FF28 but not 31
});
lttWorker.on("error", function(){callError("pageWorker failed");}); //This never gets called. Ever.
```

if anybody is interested)

EDIT: I have now tried it on Firefox 30b and there are still a load of issues, although they seem to be slightly different to both FF28 and 31...

Comment: Please use Firefox Beta 30 when playing with these apis. They are very new and didn't completely settle until 30: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/#beta

Answer (score 2):

First of all: These new functions are supported in Firefox 30 and later. See @canuckistani answer.

The `exportFunction` API is way too limited to actually inject something like jQuery with all the complex objects being or containing DOM nodes. That simply won't fly with the structured-clone algorithm that is applied to arguments.
The API is meant as a way for add-ons to communicate with pages bi-directionally, and not to inject complex libraries.

Your best bet is actually creating a script tag using the DOM APIs and putting jQuery there.

Comment: I did try that, and for some reason it wasn't working. This is what I have: `$jq("body").append($jq("<script>", {
src: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
})).append($jq("<script>").html("var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();$jq('body').hide()"));` but although the body is being hidden (so `$jq` should be defined), it's not globally defined according to firebug. I do have to use noConflict().

Comment: Looks sane enough, except for the remote code injection (you should inject a locally shipped copy if jquery)... I might look into that later...

Comment: I'm only using a remote copy of jQuery to make it easier to test because otherwise I have to mess around with sending resource URLs to the script. I would do so in production code though. Also, if I put the exact same code that's in the script tag into the FB console, it works fine.